# For some reason when i collide the tile from right or left i get teleported to the top of the tile. how can i fix this?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my collision code. i made a temp_rect cause after colliding with the ground it started teleporting around. it works fine, but when i collide witha  tile from left/right it teleports to the top

```
def collision_test(rect,tiles):
    hit_list=[]
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_list.append(tile)
    return hit_list
def collision_move(rect,movement,tiles):
    collision_types={"Top":False,"Bottom":False,"Left":False,"Right":False}
    rect_temp=pygame.Rect(rect.x,rect.y,atom.width,atom.height-1)
    rect_temp.x+=movement[0]
    hit_list=collision_test(rect_temp,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[0]>0:
            rect.right=tile.left
            collision_types["Right"]=True
        elif movement[0]<0:
            rect.left=tile.right
            collision_types["Left"]=True
    rect_temp.y+=movement[1]
    hit_list=collision_test(rect_temp,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[1]>0:
            rect.bottom=tile.top
            collision_types["Bottom"]=True
        elif movement[1]<0:
            rect.top=tile.bottom
            collision_types["Top"]=True
    return rect,collision_types
```

Comment: What is `movement`?

Comment: @user16038533    it accelerates 2 by 2 till it reaches 6 depending on its direction, and when it stops moving it goes down 2 by 2 depending on the direction till it reaches 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you test the collision along the x-axis. If a collision is detected, the position of the rectangle is corrected. Therefore you have to set `rect_temp` again, a after the collision handling along the x-axis and before the collision handling for the y-axis:

```py
def collision_move(rect,movement,tiles):
    collision_types={"Top":False,"Bottom":False,"Left":False,"Right":False}
    
    rect_temp=pygame.Rect(rect.x,rect.y,atom.width,atom.height-1)
    rect_temp.x+=movement[0]
    
    hit_list=collision_test(rect_temp,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[0]>0:
            rect.right=tile.left
            collision_types["Right"]=True
        elif movement[0]<0:
            rect.left=tile.right
            collision_types["Left"]=True
    
    rect_temp=pygame.Rect(rect.x,rect.y,atom.width,atom.height-1) # <- this is missing
    rect_temp.y+=movement[1]
   
    hit_list=collision_test(rect_temp,tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[1]>0:
            rect.bottom=tile.top
            collision_types["Bottom"]=True
        elif movement[1]<0:
            rect.top=tile.bottom
            collision_types["Top"]=True
    return rect,collision_types
```